# How to substitute some string-type values of a column with some integer values?

Tags: r

In the `veteran` dataset of R survival package, and I'm currently working on the `celltype` column. In particular, I need to substitute some integer values for the current string values of the column as follows.

```
veteran[veteran$celltype == "squamous",]$celltype <- 1
veteran[veteran$celltype == "smallcell",]$celltype <- 2
veteran[veteran$celltype == "adeno",]$celltype <- 3
veteran[veteran$celltype == "large",]$celltype <- 4
```

But R complains like this:

```
veteran[veteran$celltype == "squamous",]$celltype = 1
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

veteran[veteran$celltype == "smallcell",]$celltype = 2
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, veteran$celltype == "smallcell", ,  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `celltype` column is of type factor. This means that the labels are represented by the numbers that you already try to assign. If you want the column as integer, just do `veteran$celltype <- as.numeric(veteran$celltype)` and you will see the integers.

Comment: Usually (in my use) a column has the same data type for all rows. Suggest you use character type such as "1" instead of int type.

Comment: @LyzandeR Thanks for the hint! If you add an answer based on your suggestion, I'd gratefully accept it.

Comment: Sure I will add one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the veteran data set the column celltype is actually of type factor. Factors are treated by R as integers with labels. This is extremely useful in some of the machine learning algorithms, because they accept numbers but not strings.

In your case, since you are interested in the integers, you can just do:

```
veteran$celltype <- as.numeric(veteran$celltype)
```

and that would be enough.

You can find out more about `factors` [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) - scroll down to the Factors section.